# Derivative and and function terminology

Tags: functions, derivatives

In mathematical parlance, we say "take the derivative of a function f" to indicate that we are computing a new function, which maps slopes, that derives from f. However, in physics, we say "take the derivative of velocity". However, velocity is a quantity, not a function. What does it mean to take a derivative of a quantity? This goes for mathematics in general. If we have y = f(x), y is a quantity, not a function that maps between two sets. So what does it mean to "take the derivative of y"?

Comment: If you have something depending on something else, then you can say you are mapping from one set to another (possibly different set). For example your velocity may be changing with time or position or some other quantity. When you take the derivative, you are looking at the change or your measured quantity with respect to the quantity it depends on.

Comment: But velocity is not a mapping. It is the output to a function that links it to some other quantity (like time).

Comment: When physicists take the derivative of velocity they mean the derivative of a velocity function. Even if a particle is moving with a constant velocity it means that $v(t)$ is constant for all $t$. Your example of taking the derivative of $y=f(x)$ is a classic example of abuse of notation.

Comment: Velocity is a function of time (and possibly position or other things).

Comment: @MilesDavis: If it is a function of time, then you can view it as a mapping from your set of times to a set of velocities

Comment: I still don't understand. If we say y = f(x), then y is not the function; f is.

Comment: The terminology is looser than that. To say "$y$ is a function of $x$" means that a relationship between $x$ and $y$ exists such that the value of $x$ completely determines the value of $y$. We also describe the mechanics that determine that relationship, $f$, by the term function. Like all words, you have to decide exactly what "function" means by the context in which it is used.

Comment: @MilesDavis Saying that $y=f(x)$ is usually describing the graph of the function $f$. Your instincts are correct. The notation is ambiguous. We are really considering the set {$(x,y): y = f(x)$}. Speaking of the function $f(x)$ is technically incorrect. We can be talking about a function of one variable which we are denoting as $x$ or we can be talking about the value of $f$ at $x$. Usually, we mean the former and when we mean the latter we say $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition of derivative people see is $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ for real-valued functions $f$ of a real variable $x$.

That last clause is important. Adding "real-valued" should suggest something: You can also define functions that are not real-valued, but take their values elsewhere, say in $\Bbb R^3$, or more generally in some vector space (and even far more generally than that). All that "function" means here is that the value of $x$ completely determines the value of $f(x)$. In physics, we let the values of $f$ be vectors in space, and generally prefer the notation $v(t)$ for these vector-valued functions. Note, though, that since vectors can be added and subtracted and multiplied by scalars, the expression $\frac{v(t + h) - v(t)}{h}$ still makes sense. And because we can measure distances between vectors, the concept of limits also makes sense with vectors, which means we can still define the derivative for vector-valued functions in the same way: $$v'(t) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{v(t+h) - v(t)}{h}$$.

$v(t)$ represents a curve in space, with $t$ merely a means of specifying where one is along the curve, rather than one of the coordinates like we usually think of $y = f(x)$. $v'(t)$ will be a vector tangent to that curve at the point $v(t)$.

Comment: We use quantities f(x) and v to find derivatives. So then why do we say that we take derivatives of functions when f(x) is a value of a function at x rather than a function f?

Comment: A function is defined by the values it takes on. That is what a function is. To say anything about it, to define anything about it, is to talk about its values. So of course the derivative of a function is defined in terms of the values of that function. There no other way.